# Problemas de redimensión de well-grid

Tags: css, bootstrap

Estoy haciendo un menú cuadriculado con Bootstrap siguiendo esta estructura:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <a href="Account/frm_ghorarios" class="well-grid">
        <div class="well text-center">
            <h1 class="well-h1">Grupos horarios</h1>
            <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-big" aria-hidden="true"></i><i style="margin-left: -4px;" class="fa fa-clock-o fa-big" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <a href="Account/frm_editar_marcajes" class="well-grid">
        <div class="well text-center">
            <h1 class="well-h1">Editar turnos</h1>
            <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-big" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <a href="Account/frm_editar_marcajes_a" class="well-grid">
        <div class="well text-center">
            <h1 class="well-h1">Editar actividades</h1>
            <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-big" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

El problema lo tengo cuando, al encoger mucho la pantalla, el h1 no cabe en una línea y se separa en dos, dejando los cuadros con distinto tamaño. He creado media queries para encoger el tamaño de la letra junto con el "white-space: nowrap;", pero para pantallas pequeñas acaba por no leerse

Alguna idea?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Qué versión de Bootstrap?

Comment: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js y https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando una combinación de `display: table`, `display: table-cell` y `vertical-align:middle` se consigue que el texto se center verticalmente y no se desajuste tu menú.

Por cierto, he eliminado unos elementos `<br>` que tenías para darle más altura los elementos del menú.

```css
.col-md-4 a, .col-sm-4 a, .col-xs-4 a {
  display: table;
  min-height: 148px;
  width: 100%;
}

.well {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-top: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <a href="Account/frm_ghorarios" class="well-grid">
        <div class="well text-center">
            <h1 class="well-h1">Grupos horarios</h1>
            <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-big" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <a href="Account/frm_editar_marcajes" class="well-grid">
        <div class="well text-center">
            <h1 class="well-h1">Editar turnos</h1>
            <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-big" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <a href="Account/frm_editar_marcajes_a" class="well-grid">
        <div class="well text-center">
            <h1 class="well-h1">Editar actividades</h1>
            <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-big" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Entiendo lo que intentas hacer, pero el problema está cuando el responsive hace que una "frase" más corta (Editar turnos < Editar actividades) cabe en una única línea, pero la más larga no. Prueba ejecutando desde aquí mismo y mostrandolo en pantalla completa y mueve el ancho de la ventana verás lo que quiero decir. Gracias por responder tan rápido. Un saludo

Comment: @Andrés73 Exacto.. de eso se trata, prueba tú mismo a redimensionar y verás que no quedan líneas más largas que otras

Comment: @Andrés73 tal vez lo que intentas es que se redimensione el texto y no salte de línea? O que el texto se mantenga en una línea pero cortado y con puntos supensivos `...`? Hay muchas soluciones _aceptables_, todo depende de la solución que le quieras dar.